# How to turn off Logging to a File in Spring Boot/JPA/Hibernate Show_sql is true

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have show_sql to true in my properties because I want it to log the queries into my console when I am running our Spring Boot server app in IntelliJ. We do not have any config to write those to a file, but for some reason it is trying to write to a file. Here is what we see in a thread dump

```
"http-nio-8080-exec-2" #28 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fa208deb000 nid=0x9403 runnable [0x000070000bef8000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
- locked <0x00000006c00430b8> (a java.io.BufferedOutputStream)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:480)
- locked <0x00000006c0043098> (a java.io.PrintStream)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:104)
- locked <0x00000006c00431d8> (a java.io.OutputStreamWriter)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(OutputStreamWriter.java:185)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:527)
- locked <0x00000006c0043098> (a java.io.PrintStream)
at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:669)
at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:806)
- locked <0x00000006c0043098> (a java.io.PrintStream)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement(SqlStatementLogger.java:111)
```

All the other logging of SQL is going to the console.

```
"http-nio-8080-exec-1" #29 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fa200fef000 nid=0x110b waiting for monitor entry [0x0000700009b8c000]
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:805)
- waiting to lock <0x00000006c0043098> (a java.io.PrintStream)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement(SqlStatementLogger.java:111)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement(SqlStatementLogger.java:94)
```

I have searched everywhere in our code base to try and find anything that might make it want to log to a file, even in the run configuration of IntelliJ, but I have not had any luck.

I want it to stop logging to a file, because it ends up hanging my IDE.

Comment: Can you post application.properties file? Which version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: I can't post the application.properties (too much confidential information), but know that no file logging is configured at all. Boot version is 1.2.3.RELEASE. (And unfortunately, no we can't upgrade at this time, because it would take a couple of months for us to do that. We have a big app that would require tons of testing)